# Why do I get null value in dataBase when inserting photos?

Tags: java, mysql

I tried inserting photos into database but my database only show me null value.
This is part of my code to click the button to choose photos from my file and the photo will be displayed. Thanks in advance for help

```
btnFrontPhoto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    String s;
    @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Shopping post = new Shopping ();
        if(ShoppingDA.createPost(post)){
     JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
     fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
     FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.IMAGE", "jpg","gif","png");
     fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
     int result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
     if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
         File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
         String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
         lblFrontPhoto.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));
         s = path;
          }
     else if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
         System.out.println("No Data");
     }
        }

 }
    public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String imgPath){
        ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon(imgPath);
        Image img = MyImage.getImage();
        Image newImage = img.getScaledInstance(lblFrontPhoto.getWidth(), lblFrontPhoto.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImage);
        return image;
    }

});

 }}
```

This is the code to insert photos into my database. I am not sure which part is the problem.

```
    public static boolean createPost(Shopping post){
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    db.getConnection();

    dbQuery = "INSERT INTO registration2(photo) VALUES(?)";
    pstmt = (PreparedStatement) db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

    try {
        pstmt.setBlob(1, post.getPhoto());

        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Inserted");
            success = true;
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.terminate();
    return success;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first part you have created Shopping object 'post' but not assined values to it.

```
Shopping post = new Shopping ();
        if(ShoppingDA.createPost(post)){...}
```

And in second part you are using the same object to insert in db.